# Round robin tournament help needed

Tags: statistics

Here is the problem:

We have $12$ teams participating in a game contest.

There are $6$ different table games that each team can play.
And there are $6$ rounds of play.

Rules:

- $2$ teams cannot play each other twice
- A team cannot play the same game twice
- Each team does not have to play every other team

Can someone help create a spreadsheet showing the matchups?   (Games across the top, rounds down the side, with team matchups in the grid)

Please help
Gordon